# Import error with selenium on Mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I'm trying to import Selenium on my MacBook but when I try to run my python file I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "excelsior_jig.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

So I try to reinstall selenium but it tells me that Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Am I missing something, I don't understand why it won't import.

My code current looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

first_name = "Jake"
last_name = "Mills"
date_of_birth = "11/01/1997"
email_n = 1
email = "jakelmills+", email_n, "@gmail.com"

print email
```

Comment: what does `which python` produce?

Comment: /usr/bin/python

I've just realised, could it be due to the face that selenium is installed in /python2.7/ and which python says /python?